# How do I enable the GUI and remote desktop on Ubuntu Server 10.11 running on Amazon EC2?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, remote-desktop

Before everyone clamors "use SSH", this is NOT a server. I've to use the server images because I couldn't find the ubuntu desktop images. The EC2 virtual machine/instance will be used like a shared desktop (between 2 people) but in the cloud. Yes, they will log via the same username/password so they intentionally share the same desktop etc.

Whew, so how would I go about doing this? I've already run

```
sudo aptitude install x-window-system-core gnome-core
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop
```

BTW, the second command appears to be a superset of the first, so just the second should have been ok. Anyway, I suspect I'm missing something more, like enabling the XDMCP client on the 'server' or the VNC server on the 'server' (either option is ok, I've more familiar with VNC) or NX (quick like Windows RDP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the full default desktop environment, install the [`ubuntu-desktop` meta-package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/ubuntu-desktop).

Comment: How do I connect to the remote GUI session? eg: Does it install and kick off NX directly (at bootup) when I install ubuntu-desktop so all I do is install the NX client (on local machine) to point to the public ip?

Comment: I then also installed NX on the server for remote GUI logins. Too bad I forgot to document my installation steps :|